# Is there any way in C to terminate scanf() inputting in array without ctrl+d?

Tags: c, arrays, input, scanf

For example :I want to terminate inputting without using (ctrl+d or pressing any character) as doing this cause the program to execute and the second scanf() does not work.I am not allowed to input number of elements in the array.

```
for(i=0;a[i]<10000;i++)
 {
    if(scanf("%d",&a[i])==1)
    count++;
 }
for(j=0;a[j]<10000;j++)
 {
    if(scanf("%d",&b[j])==1)
    count1++;
 }
```

Comment: Aside from entering 20,000 numbers, it is difficult to end input "without using ... **any** character".  Certainly user must be allowed to enter some character to end input early.  If user is not allowed to enter any character, use the `ReadMyMind()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```cpp
 for(i=0;a[i]<10000;i++)
 {
    // chack that input correct
    if((scanf("%d",&a[i])==1)
    {
        count++;
    }
    else   // if input is incorrect
    {
       // read first letter
       int c = getchar();
       if( c == 'q' )
       {
           break; // stop the loop
       }
       // clean the input buffer
       while( getchar() != '\n' );
    }
 }
```

and when you want to stop entering just enter letter q instead of number

Comment: Ok. but 1st statement under else should be    char c=getchar();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to come out of first loop when `scanf()` reads a character, then you may consider reading integers using [getchar()](https://awsmcode.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/fast-integer-input-function-in-c/). You may add an extra condition to that function in the link to mark a flag when some particular character is entered.

For example if you want to end the loop when input is `X`, you can use something like this

```
int get_num()
{
    int num = 0;
    char c = getchar_unlocked();
    while(!((c>='0' && c<='9') || c == 'X'))
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    if(c == 'X')
        return 10001;
    while(c>='0' && c<='9')
    {
        num = (num<<3) + (num<<1) + c -'0';
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return num;
}

//------------//

for(i=0;;i++)
{
    temp = get_num();
    if(temp < 10000)
        count++;
    else
        break;
}
for(j=0;;j++)
{
    temp = get_num();
    if(temp < 10000)
        count1++;
    else
        break;
}
```